# Невозможно переопределить get_current_user_role () (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Данный хук проверяет роль пользователя и если роль "Administrator" то выводит дополнительные поля. Все работает, но когда нажимаю кнопку обновить данные белый экран. Апач пишет:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare get_current_user_role()
```

Код:

```
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'my_user_contactmethods');

function my_user_contactmethods($user_contactmethods){

    function get_current_user_role() {

        global $wp_roles;
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $roles = $current_user->roles;
        $role = array_shift($roles);
        return $wp_roles->role_names[$role];
    }
    $current_user_role = get_current_user_role();

if ($current_user_role == 'Administrator') {
    $user_contactmethods['phone'] = 'Phone: ';
    $user_contactmethods['adress'] = 'Adress: ';

    return $user_contactmethods;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это стандартная проблема в php. Если функция `my_user_contactmethods` вызывается дважды (а фильтры могут вызываться неоднократно ядром), то вложенная функция `get_current_user_role` не может быть переопределена и это вызывает фатальную ошибку.

Кроме того, ваш код не всегда что-то возвращает (у вас return внутри if), а это тоже может завалить сайт.

Фильтр `user_contactmethods` вызывается с двумя параметрами.

Попробуйте так:

```
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'my_user_contactmethods', 10, 2 );
function my_user_contactmethods( $user_contactmethods, $user ){
    $current_user_role = get_current_user_role( $user );
    if ($current_user_role == 'Administrator') {
        $user_contactmethods['phone'] = 'Phone: ';
        $user_contactmethods['address'] = 'Address: ';
    }

    return $user_contactmethods;
}

function get_current_user_role( $current_user ) {
    global $wp_roles;

    $roles = $current_user->roles;
    $role = array_shift( $roles );

    return $wp_roles->role_names[$role];
}
```